# Can I configure my browser to let my web app receive a right-click instead of the browser itself?

Tags: reactjs, browser, right-click

I want to be able to use a right-click in a single page (react) app. Every time I right click, the browser handles it instead of letting my app handle it. This seems to happen with Chrome and Safari. Is there a way to tell either browser to pass the right-click to the web app?

Comment: I believe the cited question doesn't answer the question because it addresses how to enable and deal with mouse clicks in a web app. My concern is that the right-click never gets to my web app and is caught by the browser itself. I expect there is a simple way to tell Chrome or Safari to not do this and let the right-click get to the app itself.

Comment: Were you looking for `event.preventDefault()`, which prevents the default context menu from opening

Answer (score 1):

`onContextMenu`

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) to get a complete list of mouse events.

Comment: I do not want the browser or OS itself to intercept the event and not pass it on.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It was not answered by the question cited. Whoever closed it did not clearly read my question.

Comment: The question is probably rather brief @SteveWebber. Can you explain - maybe in the comments under the question itself - why the proposed duplicate is not satisfactory. "Not answered by it" is in itself a rather brief explanation too. Three experienced users here took the opposite view - can you explain how they are mistaken?